# Is there an equivalent function for `test.each` from Jest in Chai?

Tags: testing, jestjs, chai

[Jest](https://jestjs.io/) provides the [`test.each`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#2--testeachtablename-fn-timeout-) function, that allows nice testing of a table driven test input matrix via *tagged templates*. Is there an equivalent function / plugin available for [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/)? I did search through the [Chai Plugins](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/) but could not find something similar.

Actually this could be also solved with a generic solution, *regardless* of the used assertion / test runner, however the only ones ([Sazerac](https://sazerac.js.org/), [Mocha Table](https://github.com/allenluce/mocha-table), [Chai Things](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-things)) I've found are either using *fluent* APIs or work on arrays, whereas I like to have them basically work with *super-charged* markdown tables:

```js
const testInput = 
`| enableMixed | oldValue   | newValue   | emitChange |
 | ----------- | --------   | --------   | ---------- |
 | ${false}    | ${false}   | ${false}   | ${false}   |
 | ${false}    | ${false}   | ${true}    | ${true}    |
 | ${false}    | ${false}   | ${'mixed'} | ${false}   |
`
```

Comment: Notice that this Jest API is used for test definitions, Chai is an assertion lib so it's irrelevant. It could be Mocha extension but it shouldn't be really tied to any framework. As long as you parsed a table to an array, it can be iterated with native JS loops and destructuring. So you basically need a lib for that.

Comment: @EstusFlask I know, that's why I asked for an equivalent function and concluded myself, that this could be done with a generic solution. I need it for Chai though and will accept either solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it seems, there is nothing really out there and I came up with my own cooked solution.

Generating [tests dynamically](https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests) as in Jest is in Mocha / Chai pretty simple and with the following helper function:

```js
/**
 *
 * This is a helper function, that parses a markdown table via a tagged template literal
 * and returns a function needing a callback to be passed; with which it is invoked
 * for each row of the table with the values filled in with the columnHeaderName
 *
 * @param tableMarkup
 * @param substitutions
 */
export function callForEachRow(tableMarkup: TemplateStringsArray, ...substitutions: any[]): (callback: Function) => void {

    const headerMarkup = tableMarkup[0];

    // filter all table headers by splitting with '|' on initial and removing everything empty after having stuff trimmed
    const keys = headerMarkup.split('|')
        .map(cellContent => cellContent.trim())
        .filter(trimmedContent => trimmedContent !== '')
        .filter(trimmedContent => trimmedContent !== '\n')
        .filter(trimmedContent => !trimmedContent.startsWith('-'));

    // determine rowCount and offset index by rowCount
    const rowCount = substitutions.length / keys.length;
    const columnCount = keys.length;

    return (callback) => {
        // invoke callback for each row
        const rows = Array.from({ length: rowCount });

        let returnPromise = false;
        // the result of each callback might either be a promise or not
        // if it is promise, wait until it resolves
        return rows.reduce((acc, current, row) => {

            // create obj for current row
            const obj = keys.reduce((acc, key, index) => {
                // and shift through substitutions by rowOffset
                acc[key] = substitutions[index + row * columnCount];
                return acc;
            }, {});

            // determine, whether we need to return a promise...
            const result = callback(obj, row);
            if (row === 0 && result instanceof Promise) {
                returnPromise = true;
                acc = result;
            }

            // if we are to return a promise, we need to sequentially execute them
            // by deferring their call to then handler of the previous one
            if (returnPromise) {
                // @ts-ignore because TS does not know, that we are dynamically changing the type
                return acc.then(() => {
                    return result
                });
            } else {
                return acc;
            }
        }, undefined);

    };
}
```

I can either generate tests dynamically (as the `test.each`) helper does:

```js
callForEachRow`
        | enableMixed  | value      | newValue   |
        | ------------ | ---------- | ---------- |
        | ${false}     | ${false}   | ${false}   |
        | ${false}     | ${false}   | ${'mixed'} |
        
        `(({ enableMixed, value, newValue }) => {
                it(`should not be dispatched if the value changes from ${value} to ${newValue} with enableMixed set to ${enableMixed} `, async () => {
                    // ...
                });
            });
```

or simply generate expectations. The passed callback can **either** be *async* **or** *sync*. If it is *async*, each callback will be called after the previous *resolved*.

This allows to have *descriptive* *data-driven* tests, instead of manually writing a lot of test cases and possible forgetting some edge cases.